# Order of operations with functions

Tags: functions

I'm unsure how order of operations works with functions.

Example: $f(n)^2$

Does the exponent apply to $n$ or $f(n)$?

Comment: I would ordinarily assume it means $[f(n)]^{2}$ (and it does NOT mean $f(n^2)\;),$ but I personally would not write it as $f(n)^{2}.$

Answer (score 2):

That would be usually understood as: $$f(n)^2 = (f(n))^2 \;\; \ne \;\; f(n^2)$$ Using the paranthesized form $(f(n))^2$ eliminates any possible confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Some extra notes about notation: $f^2(x)$ is often used to denote $f(f(x))$. But for some special function-symbols, especially for trig functions, it denotes $(f(x))^2.$ E.g., $\cos^2 x$ means $(\cos x)^2,$ and $\sin^{17} x$ means $(\sin x)^{17}.$